# Let the use edit and view an array of text values in C# (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, user-interface

I'm going to write a small linear programming solver.
The GUI will allow the user to edit a table of string values.
What is the neatest way to accomplish that in a C# Winform?
The development tool is Visual Studio 2008.

http://www.fileguru.com/GIPALS32---Linear-Programming-Library/screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control with a `DataTable` or something similar.